# Web application/ site service (like Google App Engine) for PHP/ MySQL and Postgres

Tags: web-services

I would like to find a service similar to Google App Engine for PHP/ MySQL/ Postgres sites/ applications.

We host two different types of site.

i). PHP/ Mysql/ Zend Framework

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/home/websites/website.com/public"
   ServerName website.com

   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

   <Directory "/home/websites/website.com/public">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

ii). Matrix CMS - PHP/ Postgres + loads of pear classes

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName server.example.com
DocumentRoot /home/websites/mysource_matrix/core/web

Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks

<Directory /home/websites/mysource_matrix>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>
<DirectoryMatch "^/home/websites/mysource_matrix/(core/(web|lib)|data/public|fudge)">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</DirectoryMatch>
<DirectoryMatch "^/home/websites/mysource_matrix/data/public/assets">
  php_flag engine off
</DirectoryMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.inc$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<LocationMatch "/(CVS|\.FFV)/">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</LocationMatch>

Alias /__fudge   /home/websites/mysource_matrix/fudge
Alias /__data    /home/websites/mysource_matrix/data/public
Alias /__lib     /home/websites/mysource_matrix/core/lib
Alias /          /home/websites/mysource_matrix/core/web/index.php/
</VirtualHost>
```

My key requirements are:

1. I don't want to worry/ know/ care about the server/ infrastructure
2. Secure/ up to date software/ os
3. Good monitoring
4. Automatic scalability
5. SLA

I apologise for the length of the question.

**In short all I want to do is i). create vhost, ii). create db iii). install app/ site iv). relax.**

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I include the Matrix vhost because that is the only complication that I cannot really do via a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vhost with Python ([complete source code here](http://rohablog.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/virtual-hosts-webapp-fur-google-app-engine-ermoglicht-domain-masking-multiple-hostname/)) and different Namespaces for Datastore and MemCache Entities.

```
application_default = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', DefaultMainPage)],debug=False)
application_test = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', TestMainPage)],debug=True)

def main():
  import os
  if os.environ['HTTP_HOST'].startswith('test.'): 
    run_wsgi_app(application_test)
  else: 
    run_wsgi_app(application_default)
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. As you appear to be the author why not post the script here - all the links are nofollow anyway.